# Why selenium click by JS is not always performed?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to create a python script in order to click on elements in Google Maps.
I implemented the click function by JS. Before clicking, I ensure the driver waits until the element is clickable using `WebDriverWait` and Expected Condition.

However, the click is not always performed and when not performed, no error is thrown.
I have no clue why this is working randomly.

Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.fr/maps/search/scooter+moto+v%C3%A9lo/@48.8455505,2.3772185,14z')
driver.switch_to.frame(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]")))) 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span').click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/jsl/div[3]/div[9]/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

I'd be pleased if anyone could help

Comment: it works , whats the issue you are facing ,

Answer (score 0):

With any problem in Selenium, there often isn't going to be an apparent answer without seeing the test in action.

However, one thing that looks problematic to me is your selector here: `/html/body/jsl/div[3]/div[9]/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]`. That's a very fragile selector because it relies on a LOT of positional arguments and specific structure for how elements are nested, especially since I'm assuming you don't control Google Maps. If anything in how divs appear on the page varies from that order in any way, it's not going to work.

My hunch is that your wait IS finding that element at some point, but it's not what you think it is because the DOM is changing. Depending on the state of the DOM that selector might be what you want, and it might not be.

### Don't rely on full DOM structure/hierarchy for selectors

Update that selector to be something that's much more specific and does not rely on the order of elements. I always discourage people from using xpath generators that produce selectors like that. Instead, look to see if there is a class, id, or attribute that's specific to the element you want to interact with. It could be something on the parent as well. There are a lot of ways to make xpath and css work without relying on a strict HTML structure/position. I recommend this fun/handy game for learning more about css selectors: https://flukeout.github.io/

Your first selector in your example is much better in this regard.

If you can provide a screenshot of the element on Google Maps you are trying to interact with, I could give you better examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    'https://www.google.fr/maps/search/scooter+moto+v%C3%A9lo/@48.8455505,2.3772185,14z')
driver.switch_to.frame(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]"))))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span').click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located
((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"]/div/div[not(@class)]/div)[2]')))

element.click()
input()
```

your code works fine , wait for clickable checks for both isvisible and isenabled . As above answer instead of using absolute xpath , use relative xpath by finding a unique parent

Another way of doing is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    'https://www.google.fr/maps/search/scooter+moto+v%C3%A9lo/@48.8455505,2.3772185,14z')
driver.switch_to.frame(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src, 'consent.google.com')]"))))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span').click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located
((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"]/div/div[not(@class)]/div')))

element[2].click()
input()
```

Comment: Hello, 

Thanks for answering, effectively with a relative xpath your code works fine, however I'd like to perform the click function using JS which doesn't seem to work with a relative xpath

Comment: Thanks effectively it works however I'm not sure to fully understand how you've built the relative xpath corresponding to the clicked element, imagine I want to click the second card in the results shown on Google Maps instead of the first how would you do, I know it seems a bit dumb, but I can't figure this out

Comment: (//div[@class="section-layout sectio n-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"]/div/div) change this t o 2

Comment: see the updated answer, please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign if it helped

Comment: sorry but neither the first nor the second solution works on my computer

Comment: Both updated solution throw the same error as if the relative xpath was not correct, how do you build this relative xpath from scratch ? 




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 14, in <module>
    (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"]/div/div[not(@class)]/div')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: i don't know why it works perfectly , i added the full code for both

Comment: This is really weird I still got an error : element not interactable would you mind discussing of this via chat to see what's going on ?

Comment: Sometimes this error is also fired : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click', I literally copied and pasted your code in a new file. Don't understand what's happening